# Integration of $(ae)^x$

Tags: integration

I just found that
$$\int a^x\ \text{d}x = \frac{a^x}{\log(a)}$$ 
$$\int e^x\ \text{d}x = e^x$$

But what about $$\int(a e)^x\ \text{d}x$$

I guessed it should be $\frac{(ae)^x}{\log(a)}$

But I am told I was wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(ae)^x/log(ae)$?

Comment: The given answer is : $(ae)^x / 1 + loga$

Comment: @GregoryGrant Why?

Comment: @Lovsovs I'm just replacing $a$ with $ae$ *everywhere* in your formula.  You just replaced it in one place, you have to replace it everywhere.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yeah, I see the logic. And just a note: It isn't my formula/question.

Comment: @Mahesh $(ae)^x/(1+log(a))$ is the same as $(ae)^x/log(ae)$. $log$ is meant to be natural logarithm with base $e$, ie. $log(ae)=log(e)+log(a)=1+log(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using you first result, recall that $e$ is also a constant, so relabel $ae = c$, then
$$\int (ae)^x\,dx = \int c^x\,dx = \frac{c^x}{\log c}+C = \frac{(ae)^x}{\log(ae)}+C = \frac{(ae)^x}{\log a+\log e}+C = \frac{(ae)^x}{\log a+1}+C$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint

if $a$ is a real number, then just call $ae = n$ and solve

$$\int n^x\ \text{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be obtained if you apply the by parts integration.and would get
$$I=(ea)^{x}/(1+\log a)$$

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a couple parentheses here?

Comment: I don't see why "by parts integration" would be helpful here. It's "too big weaponry" for such a simple problem.